# C Array struct, trying to access data, but is coming up with the same for all arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So, my goal is to create a linear search, but i have got that down pat, I am having one problem with accessing strings from the struct, that i have stored using a txt file, so in `linearSearch()` I tried doing this:

```
printf("Name: %s \n", q.name[i]);  
printf("Data: %d \n", q.data[i]);
```

The `data` would be perfect but `name` would just print out the same name for every array which would be the last item that I put into the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
   char* name[10];
   int data[10];
}Word;

//int bubblesort (Word word);
void linearSearch(char* name, Word q);

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]){
    Word q;
    char username[9];  /* One extra for nul char. */
    int score;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    ifp = fopen("Data.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(ifp, "%s %d", &username, &score) == 2) {
        q.name[i] = username;
        printf ("Name: %s, I = %d \n", q.name[i], i);
        q.data[i] = score;
        printf ("Data: %d, I = %d \n", q.data[i], i);
        i++;
    }
    linearSearch("Matt", q);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void linearSearch(char* name, Word q){ 
    int i = 0;
    int foundIt = 0; 
    int numNames = sizeof(&q.name);
    while ((foundIt == 0) && (i <= numNames)){
        printf("Name: %s \n", q.name[i]);
        printf("Data: %d \n", q.data[i]);
        if ((strcmp(name, q.name[i]) != 0)){
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            foundIt = 1;
        }
    }
    if (foundIt == 1){
        printf("Name found at position %d", i); 
    } else {
        printf("Required person not found"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the code

```
q.name[i] = username;
```

You cannot assign the value of an array using `=` operator. Here, you're assigning the address of `username` to every `q.name[i]`. So, the last value of `username` is reflected throughout the array.

What you actually need is to use `malloc()` to allocate memory and then `strcpy()` to copy the string contents.

Otherwise, you can also make use of `strdup()`.

Either way, don't forget to `free()` the allocated ememory once you're done using them.

Comment: I now have: strcpy(q.name[i], txtName); but it is coming up with a Segment ation Fault?

Comment: @MattSolo `q.name[i] = strdup(username);` , and don't forget to `free` them when you're done.

Comment: @MattSolo You need to allocate memory to `q.name[i]` using `malloc()` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you declared `char username[9]`, so I assume your names should be at most 8 characters long. You should :

- read with : `fscanf(ifp, "%8s %d",&username, &score) == 2` : the `&` is useless in front of an array (it decays nicely to a pointer), but you **should** limit size of input - ok , your problem does not come from there
- use a 2D char array for `Word.name` instead of an array of pointers. That way your memory is already allocated and you can safely `strcpy` to it :

  ```
  typedef struct {
     char name[10][9];
     int data[10];
  }Word;
  ```

  then :

  ```
  strcpy(q.name[i], username); /* safe because qname[i] and username are both [9] */
  ```

The rule here is *always control that you do not risk a buffer overrun when writing in char arrays*/

An alternative way would be to do dynamic allocation through `strdup` but in that case you should free it.